# Dynamic html5 audio files not loading consistently

Tags: jquery, html, audio

BACKGROUND:
I have a site that is loading audio files (1 - 50) at a time, based off of searching criteria. The user can adjust the search at any point to look through a library of thousands of audio files. The page does not refresh but via AJAX the results are provided. I can not set the audio tag to preload="auto" because if there are 50 audio tracks loading at the same time, and the search keeps changing and there is more than one person searching, then the browser will crash. This is not a big deal, since there is a solution. The solution though is not 100% bullet proof and if done the correct way can cause the loading of the audio file to completely not happen.

CODE:
To begin the loading of the audio file on mouseenter I do this:

```
$("#mainSelector").on('mouseenter', '.classOfAudioFiles', function() {
            var audio,
                strippedId,
                $last_played = $('#last_played').val();
            strippedId = this.id.substring(15);
            audio = $('#audio_'+strippedId).get(0);
            if($last_played != 'audio_'+strippedId){
                console.log('over');
                audio.play();
                audio.pause();
                audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function(){
                    console.log('ready');
                    }
                );
            }
        });
```

To play the audio file on the click of a button, but not the  play button I do this:

```
$("#mainSelector").on('click', '.classOfAudioFiles, .classOfAudioFiles2', function(event) {
            //stop all playing audio
            $.each($('audio'), function () {
                this.pause();
            });
            //variables
            var audio,
                $last_played = $('#last_played'),
                alreadyPlaying = $('#' + $last_played.val()).get(0),
                $hideLastOpened = $last_played.val().substring(6),
                stopAllActions,
                clickingTrackId;
            if(this.id.substring(0,15) == 'classOfAudioFiles2'){
                clickingTrackId = this.id.substring(16);
                console.log('title');
            }else{
                clickingTrackId = this.id
                console.log('button');
            }


            if($('#last_played').val() != 'audio_'+clickingTrackId){
                //alert($last_played+' --- audio_'+clickingTrackId);
                //hide the last opened
                $('#playTrack'+$hideLastOpened).hide();
                //show the plus sign
                $('#closePlus'+$hideLastOpened).show();
                //alreadyPlaying = 0;
            }
            //set last played
            $last_played.val('audio_'+clickingTrackId);
            //create audio
            audio = $('#audio_'+clickingTrackId).get(0);
            audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function(){
                console.log('ready2');
                }
            );

            if($hideLastOpened == $('#last_played').val().substring(6)){
                $('#last_played').val('audio_1000');
                stopAllActions = 1;
            }else{
                stopAllActions = 0;
            }


            if (alreadyPlaying != undefined && stopAllActions == 1){
                alreadyPlaying.pause();

            }else{
                //delay play
                setTimeout(function(){
                    audio.play();

                }, 250);
            }
        });
```

QUESTION:
Is there something that I am missing in either of the above codes that will ensure the audio file to play 100% of the time (the delay helped slightly but not 100%)? Is this more so a server issue, such as ram? Or is it client side dependent and so a server adjustment wont do anything?

Comment: Should you possibly use `ondurationchange` event as a trigger that playback is possible? Also if you start playback before entire audio is loaded you can't be 100% sure that it will be eventually loaded completely just because Internet is about connected[ness/less]. The only way to ensure that audio will playback completely is to allow playback after `canplaythrough` is fired.

Comment: Seems to be more responsive if I remove controls from the audio players. I wonder if that is because it is less for the browser to render?